# Jquery filter to run on several elements

Tags: jquery, filter

I have the following fiddle that works perfectly when there is only one h1 tag, but I need it to work through all h1 tags?

http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/un06y3x6/

If I remove 2 of the h1 tags this works, but with all 3 there, I should see the style applied to 2 of them. Because 2 of the h1 tags match with .duration

```
<h1>September 14</h1>
<h1>October 10</h1>
<h1>Noveber 12</h1>


<div class="tribe-events-category-ewp">
<div class="duration">Event for September 2014</div>
<div class="tribe-events-category-ewp">
    <div class="duration">September 14</div>
    <div class="tribe-events-category-ewp">
        <div class="duration">October 10</div>


</div>

$(function () {
var h1 = $('h1').text();
$('.duration').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == h1;
}).css('background-color','#ffff00');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `.filter()` correctly,Try this code :

```
$('.duration').each(function () {
    var myhtml = $(this).text();
    var ele = $(this);
    $('h1').each(function(){
        myhtml == $(this).text() ? $(ele).css('background-color','#ffff00') : ""  //or in else case instead of passing empty string you can pass null also.
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/un06y3x6/5/)

Comment: Hi Thanks,Yes that does most of what I want but I have now realised I need it to work for only the first word matching

Comment: @user1625357..you want that if div's first word if match with h1 tag complete text then apply css on that div????...i think you want this see here http://jsfiddle.net/un06y3x6/6/  or see here also http://jsfiddle.net/un06y3x6/7/

Comment: @user1625357...if above fiddle links and answer solved your problem then mark this as answer so that accepted answer help others also..thanks...